# Access 2013 query - select 1st row

Tags: sql, ms-access, greatest-n-per-group

It seems a basic questions but after several hours and days, i'm still blocked.

As part of a query I would like to select some specific rows in a table (actually this table is already a query). As an example, rows are highlighted in the picture attached. For each "batch", this corresponds to the row containing the lower "CountofVials" and is not a "Stability rack". 
How would you create the query? I usually use the Design view to create query but i can understand SQL too.

table with rows to select in yellow

[image: table with rows to select in yellow]

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourQuery a 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1  
              From YourQuery b
              WHERE b.[Stability Rack] = False AND b.Batch=a.Batch
              GROUP BY Batch
              HAVING Min(CountOfVial)=a.CountOfVial  )
```

Comment: If you already used **a** and **b** as table aliases in **YourQuery** above you should use other letters i.e **aa** and **bb**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot 'select' non-contiguous in Access. You can use a form and 'highlight' entire rows or individual values using conditional formatting. There has been much posted on conditional formatting, so it would be best to just look it up.